Snap polyline to another polyline's vertices
I have got a polyline layer which has its own vertices (blue line in image below) and another polyline layer with a slightly different alignment and vertices in different locations (red line in image below). I would like to snap the first polyline to the vertices of the second but without losing the vertices of the first (which are snapped to points in another layer). Basically I would like additional vertices to be added without losing the existing ones. I have tried using the Snap geometries to layer tool but it doesn't seem to do what I am looking for, it snaps the first polyline to the second but it gets rid of the existing vertices. Is there a way to do this in QGIS?



Extract vertices from the first (blue) layer
Snap the vertices to the second (red) line
Connect the snapped vertice with points to path


Thank you, I did something very similar: 1) extract vertices from the blue line 2) extract vertices from the red line 3) add both sets of vertices to the same point layer 4) use Snap geometries to layer with the blue line as the Input Layer and the point layer with all the vertices as the Reference Layer and that did the trick.
